# Swagger API documentation and flask-restplus: How to represent an object with a key in the body of a request

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I have this example of the parameter needed  in the body of a PUT request to my API:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "closed_date": "2018-11-20T18:42:58.946Z",
  "contact": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "status": "Open"
}
```

To have it represented in my Swagger end point documentation I did this :

```
@api.doc(body=card_change_fields)
    def put(self, card_id, *args, **kwargs):
```

Where:

```
card_change_fields = api.model('card modification', {

        'id': fields.String(description='id', required=True),
        'closed_date': fields.DateTime(description='Closed date'),
        'contact': fields.String(description='Contact'),
        'description': fields.String(description='Description'),
        'status': fields.String(description='Status', required=True,
                                enum=["Open", "Closed"])
})
```

However what I want is actually this :

```
{  card : {
  "id": "string",
  "closed_date": "2018-11-20T18:42:58.946Z",
  "contact": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "status": "Open" }
}
```

How can I do this in my flask-restplus swagger documentation ?
I tried with child and parent model and expect with no success

Thanks,
DT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use fields.Nested to use a model to be a input of another Model. Check the code below:

```
card_change_fields = api.model('card modification', {
                'id': fields.String(description='id', required=True),
                'closed_date': fields.DateTime(description='Closed date'),
                'contact': fields.String(description='Contact'),
                'description': fields.String(description='Description'),
                'status': fields.String(description='Status', required=True,
                                        enum=["Open", "Closed"])
})

card = api.model('Card', {
    'card': fields.Nested(card_change_fields, required=True)
})
```

And respectively your doc rendering will also change to:

```
@api.doc(body=card)
    def put(self, card_id, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Yes your response was correct.It works exactly as I expected. Thank you for your help.